# Using implicit wait in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver, implicitwait

I am a beginner. I understand what waits basically does but I am confused over how different tutorials over the internet place it and explain it. For example, in the below code it is placed before loading the URL. So, is it only to wait for the URL to be loaded or for finding the element or both? Is is true that if I use an implicit wait once in my try block, it will be applicable for every element search I am performing in my code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")
```

Comment: Please read the official docs to understand how it works, http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits.

Comment: @Concerned folks, please convey the motivation behind downvoting this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### ImplicitWait

[ImplicitWait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) as per the [Java Docs](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) is to specify the amount of time the *WebDriver* instance i.e. the *driver* should wait when searching for an element if it is not immediately present in the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) in-terms of *NANOSECONDS*, *MICROSECONDS*, *MILLISECONDS*, *SECONDS*, *MINUTES*, *HOURS* or *DAYS* when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is **0** which means the `driver` when finds an instruction to find an element or elements, the search starts and results are available on immediate basis.

In this case, after a fresh loading of a Webpage an element or elements may be / may not be found on an immediate search. So your [Automation Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013692/what-is-test-automation-framework-in-selenium/52705196#52705196) may be facing any of these exceptions:

- [`NoSuchElementException`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html)
- [`TimeoutException`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TimeoutException.html)
- [`ElementNotVisibleException`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotVisibleException.html)
- [`ElementNotSelectableException`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotSelectableException.html)

Hence we introduce *ImplicitWait*. By inducing *ImplicitWait* the *driver* will poll the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) until the element has been found for the configured amount of time looking out for the element or elements before throwing a [NoSuchElementException](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html). By that time the element or elements for which you had been looking for may be available in the *HTML DOM*. As in your code you have already set *ImplicitWait* to a value of **10** seconds, the *driver* will poll the *HTML DOM* for **10** seconds.

- *Python*:

  ```
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
  ```
- *Java*:

  ```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```
- *DotNet*:

  ```
  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
  ```

Finally, once you set the *ImplicitWait*, the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance i.e. the *driver* is able to carry this configuration  till its lifetime. But if you need to change the coarse of time for the *WebDriver* instance i.e. the *driver* to *wait* then you can reconfigure it as follows:

- *Python*:

  ```
  driver.implicitly_wait(5)
  ```
- *Java*:

  ```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```
- *DotNet*:

  ```
  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
  ```

If at any point of time you want to nullify the **`ImplicitWait`** you can reconfigure it as follows:

- *Python*:

  ```
  driver.implicitly_wait(0)
  ```
- *Java*:

  ```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```
- *DotNet*:

  ```
  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
  ```

---

### Answering your questions

- *...Wait for the URL...* : No, *ImplicitWait* have no effect on page loading.
- *...For finding the element...* : Yes, *ImplicitWait* will define the coarse of time the `WebDriver` instance will wait looking out for the element or elements.
- *...Implicit wait once...* : Yes, you need to configure *ImplicitWait* only once and it is applicable throughout the lifetime of the *WebDriver* instance.
- *...Every element search...* : Yes, applicable when ever `findElement()` or `findElements()` is invoked.

Comment: According to the selenium [WebDriver documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits), it is not possible to reconfigure an implicit wait:
"Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance."

Comment: @Simon What that means is that once it's set, it doesn't change for the life of the driver instance. It *can* be changed if you change it. You can test this for yourself... it works. You can essentially turn off implicit wait by setting it to 0 and then "turn it back on" by setting it to some non-zero value.

Answer (score 3):

yes, `implicit_wait` is globally applicable. so once you set it's applied to all the element.

I would not suggest to use `implicit_wait` unless your application is too slow. You could use `explicit wait` or any other wait based on your requirement from the following page.

it's a JAVADOC but implementation should be same for python as well.

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: You said its valid for all the elements, is it applicable for operations like loading the URL as well?
And I suppose I have to use explicit wait for every element I need to look for because its condition based.

Comment: there is not direct way to do this for every element, you could write your own function `i.e. click();` which does two things. 1. explicit wait with specific condition and 2. `click()`

Comment: Lets suppose say I am trying to find multiple elements through explicit wait in a single try block or a function, is writing it once enough? What will be the case when I am writing other function/try block?

Comment: how could i say that, it depends what you write in that function.

Answer (score 2):

Implicit wait is applicable for all the web elements where as Explicit wait is applicable only for the element it is specified.

Explicit wait is more intelligent and are really use full in handling Ajax on the other hand implicit wait is generally used to handle application sync issues.