# Grab and Click Button using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, findelement

There are several size options under 'SELECT SIZE' on this site: https://www.myntra.com/sports-shoes/puma/puma-men-black-eternity-nitro-running-shoes/14521968/buy

I have been trying to somehow click one button to choose size of the shoes using python selenium but every time it says "no such element: unable to locate element:.....".Here's what I have tried till now.

```
size_button = self.find_element(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR,
            'button[class="btn default outline   size-btn big selected"]'
        )
```

```
size_button = self.find_element(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR,
            'ul[class="sizes-list list-unstyled list-inline padding-md-left padding-md-bottom"]'
        )
```

```
size_button = self.find_element(
            By.XPATH,            '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/button'
        )
```

```
size_button = self.find_element(
            By.XPATH,           '//[@id="reactPageContent"]/div/div/div[4]/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/button'
        )
```

Here's the error for one of the above code:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[class="btn default outline   size-btn big selected"]"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For click on buttons this code may help you

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver", chrome_options=options)

    driver.get('https://www.myntra.com/sports-shoes/puma/puma-men-black-eternity-nitro-running-shoes/14521968/buy')

    # get all buttons by common class
    buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'size-buttons-size-button')

    # wait for first button (buttons[0]) be clickable and click
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(buttons[0])).click()
    time.sleep(3)
    
    # clicking in all buttons
    for button in buttons:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(button)).click()
        time.sleep(3)

    driver.quit()
```

> note1: you can use for example `buttons[0].click()` but the button may not loaded, giving for you a error

> note2: in this example i used the class as selector but you have countless selector options (in future, with more experience, you will be able to choose the clearest selector!)

Comment: Thankyou Mitaharumi, That's exactly what I was looking for. But there's a little confusion, It's working but I can't see the class 'size-buttons-size-button' anywhere in inspect element. What I see is 'btn default outline   size-btn big' class for buttons.

Comment: Edit: The reason I was unable to see right class because I inspected it using F12 key and then manually founded the button element. Now I used the extension named 'Absolute Enable Right Click & Copy'. Now I can see the accurate class.

Comment: i usually use f12, try to search a little about selectors if you are confused about how get element

Answer (score 0):

To click on *Size **6*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.myntra.com/sports-shoes/puma/puma-men-black-eternity-nitro-running-shoes/14521968/buy')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='size-buttons-size-button size-buttons-size-button-default size-buttons-big-size']//p[text()='6']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: myntra6]

Comment: Thankyou somuch you were fast and accurate,its working. I got a question if you don't mind. I was already using implicit wait, how come it didn't work?

Comment: [implicitly_wait()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45674706/7429447) isn't effective on dynamic pages. [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) is the way forward.