# Java.IllegalMonitorStateException thrown because of Selenium webdriver code driver.wait(0)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the following Selenium webdriver code and I am getting an exception at the `driver.wait(0)` line. I am using the wait statement to wait for a popup window to be loaded and allow the test to execute.

Here is a copy of my stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at Test.MounaTest.test(MounaTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Here is the code:

```
    package Test;
    
    // Generated by Selenium IDE
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.junit.After;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
    import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    public class MounaTest {
      private static WebDriver driver;
      private Map<String, Object> vars;
      JavascriptExecutor js;
      @BeforeEach
      public void setUp() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      }
      @AfterAll
      public static void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
      }
      public String waitForWindow(int timeout) {
            try {
              Thread.sleep(timeout);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Set<String> whNow = driver.getWindowHandles();
            Set<String> whThen = (Set<String>) vars.get("window_handles");
            if (whNow.size() > whThen.size()) {
              whNow.removeAll(whThen);
            }
            return whNow.iterator().next();
          }
      @Test
      public void test() throws InterruptedException {
            driver.get("https://tinder.com/");
            System.out.println("MOUNA CAMELIA");
            driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1552, 840));
            driver.wait(0); 
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Miw\\(120px\\) .l17p5q9z")).click();
            driver.switchTo().frame(0);
            vars.put("window_handles", driver.getWindowHandles());
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ssJRIf")).click();
            vars.put("win8338", waitForWindow(2000));
            vars.put("root", driver.getWindowHandle());
            driver.switchTo().window(vars.get("win8338").toString());
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".fFW7wc-ibnC6b-r4m2rf:nth-child(4) > .fFW7wc-ibnC6b-ssJRIf")).click();
            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(vars.get("root").toString());
            {
              WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Terms"));
              Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
              builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
            }
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Sq\\(28px\\) > path")).click();}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
```

...at the line `driver.wait(0);` implies that it isn't a valid line of code as per current [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) *Java* bindings. Hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

Incase you are looking for a hardcoded wait, you need to replace the line with:

```
Thread.sleep(3000); //program execution gets halted for 3 seconds
```

You can also induce [ImplicitWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45674706/7429447), then you need to replace the line with:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10)); //forces the driver will poll the HTML DOM for 10 seconds.
```