# No Such Method error while using implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, implicitwait

```
ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$Timeouts org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$Timeouts.implicitlyWait(java.time.Duration)
```

This error is coming when I removed deprecated implicit wait to latest one.

Please any one provide me a solution to resolve this.

To launch a browser successfully

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The most likely cause is that you're combining incompatible versions of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The current notation for [`implicitlyWait`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45674706/7429447) uses the `Duration.ofSeconds(n)` as the unit of time and can be implemented as follows:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```